# Magento 2 how to hide attribute at Layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, layered-navigation

I would like to **hide some attributes** at **left layered navigation**  based on the **category & category's filters** ?

Can any one suggest how to achieve this in Magento 2?

**For Example:** Travel is an attribute that should hide based on the category filter...

[image]

Comment: Please explain more details. It's better to give some examples.

Comment: sure i will update my post

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh i have update answer please have a look and suggest me thanks